# extracting the year from a string and prefixing 20 in front of it

Tags: java

I have a date stored string variable like this shown below

```
String s = 05/07/13
```

this date which is stored in string is in the format of `dd/MM/YY`

now i want to extract the yy from it that is 13 in this case and prefix 20 in fron of it that is it will become 2013 and then finally storing them into the int y so

```
int y will be equal to 2013
```

please advise how to achieve this in java , I am using java 5

Comment: Convert it to a `Date` object using a `SimpleDateFormat` then format it back to the format you really want

Comment: What if it's `05/07/99` it will become `2099` ? Better to use `Date` API of Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this utility method:

```
public static String changeDateStringFormat(String oldDateString, String oldFormat, String newFormat){

    //assertions

    String newDateString = null;

    try{
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
        Date oldDate = formatter.parse(oldDateString);
        formatter.setPattern(newFormat);
        newDateString = formatter.format(oldDate);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //It would actually be better to throw the exception
    }

    return newDateString;
}
```

Example:

```
changeDateStringFormat("05/07/13","dd/MM/yy","dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad way but easy

```
String zz="05/07/13";
    String xx=zz.split("/")[2]; //split the string
    String news="20"+xx; //concat with 20
    System.out.println(news);
```

**output: 2013**

Good way but difficult

```
String s = "05/07/13";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    Date d = (Date)formatter.parse(s);
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(d);
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

**output: 2013**

Answer (score 1):

first split the string,  get the last part and add the prefix:

```
String[]  s = str. split("/") ;
String yy =s[2];
String result = "20" + yy;
int out = Integer.parseInt(result) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = 05/07/13
String[]  array = s.split("/"); //This splits the string s into 3 parts.
String getString =array[2]; //Now extracting the 3rd part. Here  getString=13 . Taking the index number 2 of Array because we need 13.
String finalResult = "20" + getString;
int y = Integer.parseInt(finalResult) ;
```

Comment: Maybe a little explanation?

Comment: I specifically wrote the things as comment. I can summarize it:

You have a String s. Now you used a splitter which uses ("/") as delimeter. This mean. It will splits the String s in the parts whenever this delimeter exists. Since / occurs 3 times, hence String [] array length would be 3. Now String array[2] would be 13.

And then rest is concatenation and Parsing,

Comment: Just a suggestion: don't prefix variable names with `get`. In Java, the convention is that accessor methods (those which return the value of a member variable) should start with `get`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it in two lines:

```
String yearString = "20"  + ( s.split("/") )[2];
int  yearInt = Integer.parseInt(yearString);
```

1. `s.split("/")` will "split" the string into three strings, creating a three part string array using the slash as a delimiter.
2. The parenthesis around this statement allow us to use the array notation `[2]` which will return the third element of the array, which in your case is **13**.
3. Finally, we can convert the resulting *yearString* to an integer using the **Integer** Java class using its `parseInt`(...) method.

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score 0):

Java includes classes to parse String representations of date-time values. Java even has *two* such groups of classes, some old ones and some ones. The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34013451/642706) by SpringLearner shows the old way. Let’s look at the new way.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

## Example Code

First we define a formatter using a pattern to match our expected input String.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy");
```

The java.time framework includes a class to represent a date-only value, without time-of-day: [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
String input = "05/07/13";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter );
```

You can ask to extract the year number.

```
int year = localDate.getYear();
```